# Why does this work in phpMyAdmin but not in php script?

Tags: php, mysqli, phpmyadmin

When I paste the following into phpmyadmin, it correctly returns 719 records.

```
SET SQL_BIG_SELECTS=1;
select lc.townshipnumber, lc.sectionlegal, sum(fm.acres) FROM lc join fm on 
lc.parcelnumber = fm.parcelnumber join fp on fm.type=fp.soiltype join fc on 
(fp.soilgroup=fc.soilgroup and fp.soilclass=fc.soilclass) where townshipnumber 
<=20 and sectionlegal<=36 and sectionlegal>=1 and fm.year = '2013' group by 
townshipnumber, sectionlegal";
```

When I paste it into the php script, I use `$query = (*the select statement from above*)` and then  `$result = $mysqli->query($query) or die ("Errorr in query: $query. ".mysqli_error());`

The next lines in the php script show the records found, but the screen just remains empty for this particular query.

```
$records_found=mysqli_num_rows($result);
echo $records_found.' Records Found<br /><br />';
```

Comment: `SET SQL_BIG_SELECTS=1`, set it before your main query and it will work .. PHP won't execute both commands together.

Comment: You cannot run multiple queries at once with `query()`. Execute them separately or use [mysqli_multi_query](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php)

Comment: The problem has evolved.  I reduced my entire php program to 2 lines

echo "show this";
SET SQL_BIG_SELECTS=1;

I just get an empty screen unless I comment out the second line, then the words "show this" appear on screen just fine.

I'm using HostMonster.  I really thought I was able to use sql_big_selects before, but it won't work now.  I'll probably contact HostMonster as a next step.

Answer (score 0):

You have the result as an object and you haven't actually done anything useful with it yet. You can make it into an array and loop through it to get the results.

```
<?php 
     // Save the query results in an array, which you can then loop through
     var_dump(mysqli_fetch_array($result));
```

Comment: I use $row = mysqli_fetch_row($result) later on in my code and then I process it further.  The problem is that it just hangs on the empty screen before it even gets to the line that should display the number of records found.  If it would just say "719 records found", I would be okay.